Not able to see context menu dialog on UI and trace mode (Playwright with Typescript)
Trying to verify and expect dialog messages. but can't able to visualize in ui and trace mode.
it displays the page context menu dialog when I run &  open the Chromium browser (VS code Extension).
test("Verify Context menu dialog", async ({ page }) => {
    page.on("dialog", async (dialog) => {
      await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
      expect(dialog.type()).toContain("alert");
      expect(dialog.message()).toContain("You selected a context menu");
      await dialog.accept();
    });
    await page.locator("#hot-spot").click({ button: "right" });
  });

context menu alert dialog should be display when i execute playwright test using ui and trace mode.
